# Simulating and manipulating a partitioned database on multiple locations

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

Let's say that I created the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 
( 
id INT NOT NULL
country VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
productType VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

If for example I have different values for producType ( type1, type2 .. etc)
and I do a partitioning based on those types such as partition1 is for type1 and so on.
And the possible values for country are : country1, country2 and country3.
How can I perform or simulate a horizontal fragmentation based on the country, and be able to use a similar command to this :

```
SELECT * FROM partition1@country1
WHERE name = someName
```

Is it a requirement that the database has to be stored on multiple servers in order to be able to do that? 
If so, is there another way to do it that doesn't require that (on Oracle 11g) ?

Comment: Sharding (physical partitioning) is not supported before 12c. But if you don't want the countries to reside on multiple servers then you're not talking about sharding anyway. So  what do you want?

Comment: Table Partitioning isn't considered sharding? I'm doing an assignment in which I have to do a horizontal fragmentation that also has to be based on location, so I'll have to use some commands in which I will have to specify the location like " @countryName " and I don't know if it's possible to do that in Oracle 11g without having multiple servers but only partitioned tables.

Comment: No. Sharing is splitting a table across the multiple database instances. Partitioning​ is organising the layout of a table within one database.

Comment: That command can only be used when there are multiple database instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to subpartition the tables? That is, partition by list( ProductType), subpartition by list (country)?

That can be done.

Subpartitions have generated names which don't reflect the name of the key. So they don't lend themselves to explicit referencing the way partitions can The select statement would reference the country in the WHERE clause:

```
select * from your_table partition (p_prodtype_0001)
where country = 'country1'
```

The optimizer can still apply subpartition pruning in this case.

You could fake sharing by having different tables of the same name in different schemas, either in the same database or different ones. You could create database links with the name of your different countries. That would allow you to employ `@country1` or whatever. Inserting would be tricky. Probably you would have to have a view and an INSTEAD OF trigger.